# Access Denied Error when using ZipFile Class

Tags: c#, compression

**Background**

I currently have a usb device which has all my projects which I am working on and it stays in my office's docking station.  Last night I was bored and wanted to continue work on a project, However no files?  This made me think about writing a console app that would copy all the files from my usb drive to a folder on my desktop and would run as a scheduled task at a certain hour.

**Problem**

I am trying to use a System.IO.Compression.FileSystem in order to compress the file in order in order to then move it to a new directory on my PC.  The documentation gives an example here  [ZipFile class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx).  IT seems very up front.  However, when I am trying to copy it to a new destination I get the following error.

**Error**

*Message*

```
Access to the path 'C:\Users\er4505\Desktop' is denied.
```

*StackTrace*

```
  at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.Open(String archiveFileName, ZipArchiveMode mode, Encoding entryNameEncoding)
   at System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.DoCreateFromDirectory(String sourceDirectoryName, String destinationArchiveFileName, Nullable`1 compressionLevel, Boolean includeBaseDirectory, Encoding entryNameEncoding)
   at System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(String sourceDirectoryName, String destinationArchiveFileName)
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\FTG\Projects\CaseWare\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 25
```

**Code**

```
 string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
 string[] folders = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(@"D:\", "*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
 foreach (string folder in folders)
 {
     ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(folder, path); << errors out here!
 }
```

Comment: what are the permissions set for the particular folder on your desktop.. the error seems pretty straight forward to me.. also what is `TempDir` used for in your code..? doesn't look relevant to your current code that you have posted.. also use the debugger.. and step through the code start with the basics first.. if that doesn't work then create a folder on your local `"c:\"` drive and try copying it there via the code.

Comment: @MethodMan Correct Temp Dir is not relevant to this code sample, will update the code block.

Answer (score 2):

The 2nd parameter `string destinationArchiveFileName` should be a filename.
for Example `"C:\Users\er4505\Desktop\example.zip"`

Comment: I tried that, but I get the exception `C:\Users\blah\example.zip does not exist` - Even though it should create the `example.zip` in the directory..